# changing column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I just want to rename one column in my table from `tenant_id` to `organization_id`
I saw this post about it http://blog.techsoftsolutions.net/?p=340   but the whole thing seemed too much for just a "rename" and I thought maybe that's because his column was a password column and was more complicated. 
So in latest rails - 3.2? - is that still what we should do to rename a column? I was hoping a one liner migration command exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked less steps than the previous link:

http://qatechnotes.blogspot.com/2011/07/renaming-database-column-using-rails.html